# How to pass values from Callback into another method

Tags: java, android, callback, viewmodel, geofire

```java
private Flowable<List<String>> getInfo(){

    List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    return BehaviorProcessor.create(emitter->{

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("url")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (null != dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {

                                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                        final MyClass myClass= postSnapshot.getValue(MyClass.class);
                                        String key = postSnapshot.getKey();
                                        String firsnName = myClass.getFirstName();

                                        myList.add(0, key);
                                        myList.add(1, firsnName);
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

    }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
}



private Flowable<GeoLocation> setMyLocation(){
Flowable.create(emitter -> {

geoFire.setLocation(key, new GeoLocation(myLastLocation.getLatitude(),
                myLastLocation.getLongitude()), (k, e) ->{
            
        });

});

}
```

I would like to pass the values in my list into my next method. Specifically,  I need to pass my key into the setLocation method of GeoFire as the key as shown. I do understand onDataChange is called asynchronously and I am used to doing it in my Activity class using a callbackListener. How can I do the above in my ViewModel? I am open to change the whole implementation for a working solution.

I am using ViewModel, LiveDataReactiveStream in Android Java. I would hope to get help finding a solution using RxJava inside my ViewModel.

Thanks.

Comment: what is `myList` ? and where is it declared ?

Comment: @bubbles I have edited to instanstiate myList. I am using myList to store the fields I get back from the datasnapshot.

Comment: there's a compilation error here ? `Flowable<List<String>> getInfo()` but you're returning a list !

Comment: @bubbles I have made edits. No more compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `List`, create your own object, say `Info` :

```java
class Info {
   private final String key;
   private final String firstName;

   public Info(String key, String firstName) {
     this.key = key;
     this.firstName = firstName;
   }

   ...
}
```

Your `getInfo` then will be like :

```
private Flowable<Info> getInfo(){

    return BehaviorProcessor.create(emitter->{

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("url")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if (null != dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.hasChildren()) {

                                    for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                        final MyClass myClass= postSnapshot.getValue(MyClass.class);
                                        String key = postSnapshot.getKey();
                                        String firstName = myClass.getFirstName();

                                        // use emitter here
                                        emitter.onNext(new Info(key, firstName))
                                    }

                                }
                            }
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        // use emitter here
                        emitter.onError(/*error*/)
                    }
                });

    }, BackpressureStrategy.LATEST);
}
```

and then change the signature of your `setMyLocation` to accept the key.

After that use `concatMap` operator to chain your requests :

```java
getInfo()
  .concatMap(info -> setMyLocation(info.key))
  .subscribe();
```

Hope this helps